# Increased data in one table is impacting performance of other

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

Step 1:
Small amount of data in all tables (around 10)

```
select * from table1;
```

This query takes 40-50ms. This table has only 1 record

Step 2:
We load a million records in table2, table3...table7.
We run the same query on **table1**.

```
select * from table1;
```

This query takes more than 100ms. This almost remains same even after multiple hits. Doesn't become any faster. This table still has only 1 record

Both times it does Seq Scan. Planning and execution time in both the cases in almost same. Together around 0.5 ms.

What is causing the second query to take such a long round trip overall? Both steps are done in same network conditions.

How does loading more data in other tables impacting the overall performance of table1.

I have updated the plan of the query below as well

```
postgres=# explain (analyze, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) select * from ss_organizations;
                                                      QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on public.ss_organizations  (cost=0.00..12.50 rows=250 width=298) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
   Output: id, schema_name, created_ts, updated_ts, name, code, created_by_id, updated_by_id
   Buffers: shared hit=1
 Planning Time: 0.044 ms
 Execution Time: 0.019 ms
(5 rows)

Time: 104.145 ms
```

Comment: 40 milliseconds to get one record, that is imho extremely slow. Could you please share the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS, SETTINGS) for your SQL statements? And share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved?

Comment: By the way, when reading this topic again, if the execution of your query takes 0.5 milliseconds, the rest of the time could have been spent on the network or application.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using `explain (analyze, buffers, format text)` (_not_ just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Adding the extra data might have pushed the data in table1 out of cache. If you're using a HDD, it might take some time to move the heads. Is your second (100ms) result repeatable or is it faster after the first read?

Comment: The other tables have no impact.

Comment: Hi all, Thank you for helpful responses. I have updated the question to include the query plan. Also, @SimonGoater, The query doesn't become any faster even after executing it multiple times.

Comment: Are you connecting to the unix-domain socket, or to the loop-back device, or over a network?

Comment: Hi all, I'm doing this over network. I think the problem is with google cloud sql. When I did the same experiment in a VM, the performance seems fine. It's coming almost equal to the network latency in ms. I will update you all here again once I get some support from Google cloud.